# Why "[how] many"?

Tags: questions

I've recently started learning Norwegian and I find that much of much of the language maps quite naturally into English, but there are a few phrases that don't.   In English we say "how many" when requesting a quantity.   In Norwegian they say "hvor mange", or "where many" where "hvordan mange" would have been how many.

I have talked to a few people here about it, but they seem to think it is just normal (how I thought of how many until now).

My question though is why do we say "how many"? It doesn't seem to match the other usages of 'how' that I can think of (otherwise replaced by "in what way").

Comment: "How much?" is the same, by the way. Note that German has "wieviel", which is also literally "how much"; the same German word is used in "wie geht es dir" ("how's it going", or "in what way is it going") as well as Wiktionary's example "Ich weiß nicht, wie die Katze hereingekommen ist" ("I don't know how the cat got in").

Comment: 1st words American babies learn when offered candy!  How MANY!

Comment: Italians ask about "quantity" *quanto* (how much) and *quanti* (how many). I suppose, in English,  it would make greater sense to ask someone: "what quantity?" (mass) and "what number?" (countable). Interesting reflection yours.

Comment: ***How relevant is it*** to point out that ***how*** in English can often be directly replaced by ***to what degree/extent**?*

Comment: Off topic, but "where many" doesn't sound logical either. I'm now wondering if there are there languages that do have something logical. "What many" or something?

Comment: @fumblefingers I don't think it is necessarily relevant except that I understand words in terms of what other words/phrases can replace a word/phrase, and I didn't see other instances of how as "to what degree" brought up by Colin

Comment: I agree that "where many" doesn't make sense, although to be honest only the spanish/french/Italian cuanto-esque words make sense to me.  Although I also like mari-lou's comment about what quantity, although it sounds a bit awkward (I can't imagine asking someone what quantity of apples they will buy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the answer precisely, but I can give some thoughts

1. One of the meanings of *how* in English is "to what degree?"; so, not just "how many?", but also "how far?", "how quickly?"
2. *How* and *where* both have their origins in case-marked forms of the Germanic interrogative pronoun, that underlies *what* (and *who*).
3. I don't find it surprising that the ranges of meanings that these forms have acquired do not coincide in all Germanic languages.

Note that in English *where* also functions as the combining form of *what*: "wherefore", "whereupon" etc. This is identically true *mutatis mutandis* for German ("wovon", "woaus"), and I suspect for other Germanic languages, though I don't know. This surely has its origin in "where-" as an oblique case of "what".

*Hvordan* is transparently a compound of *hvor* and *dan*, and I suspect its origin is just like "wherefore" and "woaus" in English and German.

Comment: I had not considered the "to what degree" interpretation of how, and not surprisingly far/quickly are mapped to hvor in Norwegian also.

Answer (score 1):

It's always been this way in English:

> On hu manegum wisum is godes weorc?
>   *In how many ways is God's work?*
>   <sub>Ælfric's Anglo-Saxon translation of *Interrogationes* in [Old English Literature and the Old Testament](https://books.google.com/books?id=OPBv9DIVf0oC&pg=PA35)</sub>

There are other OE expressions that also mean "how many/much", like *hu fela*, *hu micel*, *hu swiþe*.

It's worth noting that *who*, *what*, *where*, *why*, and *how* all come from the same source ultimately: [Proto-Germanic *hwaz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/hwaz), which is from PIE *kʷos, *kʷis.